# Wordpress do_shortcode function implementation after loop

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am doing a project on wordpress theme. Wordpress has a function call do_shortcode but when I implement it, the code is not working. The output of the $metagallery is 
[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="1" gal_title="Gallery 1"]

Why isn't it working when I echo using the function do_shortcode?

```
<?php 
$metagallery = get_post_meta($id, '_jdev_custom_meta', true);
?>
<?php if ($metagallery!="") { ?>
<div class="row clearfix galleryarea" >
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 column">
        <div class="row clearfix" >
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="gallerycontent">

                        <h2>Gallery</h2>
                        <?php 


                        echo do_shortcode($metagallery); ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the result of `$metagallery`?

Comment: What does is gives if you wrap it up like `echo do_shortcode('.$metagallery.');` ?

Comment: no output at all. haha. I am using the photo gallery http://web-dorado.com/products/wordpress-photo-gallery-plugin.html 
The output of the $metagallery is [Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="1" gal_title="Gallery 1"]

Comment: Is it working if you use it like `echo do_shortcode('[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="1" gal_title="Gallery 1"]');` ?

Comment: It works when i use that way.

Comment: Solved it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Solved it. When i view in html, it is:

```
[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="1" gal_title="Gallery 1"]
```

But when viewing in source code, it looks like this:

```
[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id=&quot;1&quot; gal_title=&quot;Gallery 1&quot;]
```

The double quote changes to special characters. Thus have to decode it.
By applying htmlspecialchars_decode it solve the problem

```
<?php echo do_shortcode((htmlspecialchars_decode($metagallery))); ?>
```